# With iOS 8.x, Characters are broken in WebVTT for subtitle

Tags: ios, objective-c, m3u8, http-live-streaming, webvtt

**ADDITION** : It seems to work correctly on other native apps. Broke on  web browsers ONLY. (ie. Chrome, Mobile Safari)

Using HLS (=.m3u8) for providing adaptive streaming, and considering to use WebVTT for subtitle. But I found out some characters, except English, happened to be broken on iOS 8.x devices when I played them on Mobile Safari. It works well on iOS 7 device.

Here’s an official sample video(.m3u8) web page hosted from Apple:
https://developer.apple.com/streaming/examples/advanced-stream.html

If you load this on both on iOS 7.x and iOS 8.x devices, select Japanese subtitle, then it will display broken characters on iOS 8.x (okay for 7.x and below):

[image]  [image]

Any ideas to avoid? I've tested this on iOS Simulator (7.1, 8.1, 8.2 beta 4) and iOS devices(8.0.2, 8.1.2).

Answer (score 2):

There has been no answer since I've posted this and I still have got struggled with this issue. However, I give you my 4-months-workaround and trivia here:

- There are two environments for native iOS video playback feature: 
  **HTML5 Video** & **Native app playback SDK** (such as AVPlayer)
- You can provide **multiple** subtitle feature by using WebVTT. This is an **ONLY** option unless you have 3rd party renderer or something from your backyard.
- If you wanna implement your own subtitle feature, you must start considering how to handle the controller UI of video player. One example of them, you can't use built-in full screen feature with your subtitle renderer. I think, if your subtitle-base isn't WebVTT (or such as .SRT, which is similar to .VTT), then implementing a subtitle renderer isn't a bad idea. (In my case, I implemented a subtitle converter to create .VTT subtitle files, though)
- Trivia of iOS HTML5 video :

  - You can provide WebVTT by embedding them into HLS playlist, and also by putting  element into  element.
  - >= iOS 8.0, if you provide WebVTT files by embedding them into HLS playlist, then multibyte characters would get broken. (*This has been my problem, as described above*)
  - If you provide WebVTT files by putting  element into  element, simply it works everywhere. (at least >= iOS 6.0. I didn't check older versions)
  - CSS styling works. It means that you can colorize your subtitle.
- Trivia of iOS HTML5 video :

  - You should embed all WebVTT into HLS playlist to use iOS built-in subtitle feature. There is no other way.
  - CSS styling not works. No text coloring.
  - Multibyte character not gets broken. Peace.

I hope you a good luck, if you fell into this subtitle hell :(